# Setup CNAME for subdomain issue

Tags: nginx, django, cname-record

I would setup for this:

- user go to test.example_site1.org
- test.example_org1.org it's a CNAME of test.example_org2.org
- user will see the page of test.example_org2.org

On the example_org2.org server I use nginx and I have 3 django projects.

test.example_org2.org shows the third django project. http://example_org2.org shows the first django project.

The problem is that I've setup a CNAME on the example_org1.org for pointing test.example_org1.org to test.example_org2.org , but if I try to go to http://test.example_org1.org I see the **first** django project, which one configurated to the main domain and not to subdomain. Otherwise if I go directly to http://test.example_org2.org all it works and I see my correct project.

Why this issue?

Comment: might help if you show some conigs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CNAME` are there only to say *sub1.domain has the same IP than sub2.domain*. But it does not tell a web server that they should serve the same content.

When you enter the domain name on your browser, it checks the IP via a `DNS` query, and it gets an answer saying *this is a CNAME for test.example_org2.org, which points to IP 1.2.3.4*. Then, the browser connects to this IP, and sends a `Host` header with a value of `test.example_org1.org` (because that  is what you requested). `Ngnix` gets this, and as it doesn't know anything about it (is not in its config) then it serves the first virtualhost it has.

You could tell the default virtualhost that if someone asks for `test.example_org1.org` then it should be redirected to `test.example_org2.org` (untested):

```
if ($host ~* "^test.example_org1.org$"){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://test.example_org2.org permanent;
  break;
}
```

Comment: "If is Evil" http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Agreed. He could use plain rewrite, but again, it was an example ;).

Comment: Unfortunately these examples are getting copied all over the Internet

Comment: I'd bother on *all over their site* rather than *all over the internet*. Anyway, if it bothers him (or you ;)) that much, he could try `rewrite ^/(django/path/to/app)(/.*)?` http://test.example_org2.org/$1$2 permanent`, but there is no way to know what hostname is being requested (not that I know of). If someone does, enlighten us.

Comment: @Torian `CNAME` records are to say: "test.example_org1.org  name is an alias for another domain: test.example_org2.org", they do not deal with ip addresses.  An `A` DNS record however does and that's what he needed to do what he wanted.

Answer (score 5):

what about adding test.example_org2.org to the server_name along with test.example_org1.org

```
server {
   server_name test.example_org1.org test.example_org2.org;

...
}
```

Comment: I had a A record with my own subdomain, but I wanted to mask the actual address with a CNAME, and I would always get the default_server served. This fixed it for me.